# How can I get the search string from incremental regexp search to use with replace regexp

Tags: regular-expressions, search, replace, isearch, query-replace-regexp

If I want to do a `replace-regexp` I usually start with a `isearch-forward-regexp` so I can get immediate visual feedback on the search string.

From there I'd like to grab the search string for using in the `replace-regexp`. Right now all I can see to do is use my OS to copy and paste it. Is there a way to do this built in? I had hoped those commands shared history but it didn't in my experiments.

Or is my whole approach wrong?

(Using spacemacs if that adds anything useful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for interactive use? I suppose so.  As the doc string for `replace-regexp` says:

```lisp
    This function is for interactive use only; in Lisp code
    use `re-search-forward' and `replace-match' instead.
```

Are you really asking about `replace-regexp`, and not `query-replace-regexp`?

Because if you use the latter then the answer is included in Isearch by default: Just use `C-M-%` when you're regexp-isearching, and you immediately switch to `query-replace-regexp`, using the search regexp as the regexp to search for with `query-replace-regexp`. And of course with `query-replace-regexp` you can always hit `!`, to replace all subsequent matches.

But if you really want to use `replace-regexp` explicitly then you can use [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) to get the regexp you use with `C-M-s`, to use it as the regexp to use with `replace-regexp`.  For that, you just use `M-w` while isearching, to copy the current search pattern to the kill ring.  And then use `M-x replace-regexp` and use `C-y`, to yank that regexp as the one to use for that command.

If you want this behavior and you don't want to load library [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) then you can just use the code for it:

```lisp
(defun isearchp-kill-ring-save ()       ; Bound to `M-w' in `isearch-mode-map'.
  "Copy the current search string to the kill ring."
  (interactive)
  (kill-new isearch-string)
  (let ((message-log-max  nil)) (message "Copied search string as kill"))
  (sit-for 1)
  (isearch-update))

(define-key isearch-mode-map "\M-w" 'isearchp-kill-ring-save)
```

Comment: Aha! Perfect! C-M-% is exactly what I was looking for.